# Impact of setting promise to empty object

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a use case where the user makes a selection.  I initiate a promise.  With the most basic case, the user makes a second selection and the promise gets resolved.

In a more complex use case, the user makes a second selection that results in having to 'start over'.  So what I want to happen is that the outstanding promise is 'cancelled' and a new promise is initiated.

I am new to promises and am working with the bluebird library.  I played around with .cancel() but that did not seem to work as required.  From what I could tell the promise still existed.  Future iteration then started tripping over each other.

What did work is creating the promise as such:

var el = Promise.resolve( id );

and then when canceling simply:

el = {};

As I noted, everything seems to work fine.  My question is this, is setting a promise to an empty object causing any harm?  Am I leaving code out there that will never resolve?  Am I missing something basic?

Comment: Got an example where this generates unwanted behavior? `el = {}` wont cancel any promise, it just assigns `el` (variable!, not the promise) to a new object.

Comment: Did you enable cancel in the config? It is off by default. http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.config.html

Comment: @IrkenInvader: I did enable it.

Comment: @Caramiriel: That is my concern.  Reassigning the variable works in my code fine.  But what does it mean to leave that promise?  Does it stay in memory and build up over time, almost like a memory leak? Maybe I simply should cancel the promise and then reassign variable?  I honestly did not think about doing both.

Comment: Why not just `reject()` the original promise with a particular `reason` that tells the calling code why it was rejected so it can act accordingly?  Or, you can just start a new operation that is now chained onto the original promise and when the new operation resolves or rejects, that will become the result of the original promise.  That makes the calling code simpler since it doesn't have to know about any of the internals.  Eventually, it just gets a resolve or reject.

Comment: @PhillipZ bluebird does not leak memory over uncared for promises - but you should consider cancellation definitely - show us your use case.